# Ajax response empty GET

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, get

Im using ajax with javascript and data is processed on a php page with GET. Is it possible to send data from the php page when the GET query is empty? I want to do that because I have a live search that filters results but I want matching results to be displayed when users enters something in the search box and string matches it and when field is empty, I want all results to be displayed. So if a user enters something in the search box and get a matching result and then presses backspace to delete it, I want all results to appear. So obviously the best way would be to be able to do something on the php page when when the query is empty but when I do that it doesnt work. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

So the javascript page looks like this:

```
function showResults(str) {
if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "query.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

}

Php page looks like the following:

```
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

if ($q !== "") {
 ....Get Data from database or elsewhere here

 echo $reponse;

}
```

If I do the following on the php page it doesnt work:

```
if ($q == "") {
 ....Get Data from database or elsewhere here

 echo $reponse;

}
```

If I check with empty or with isset it also doesnt work propery.

Only place I can do something when search input is empty is on the javascript page

```
 if (str.length == 0) { 
   document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
  return;
}
```

How can I make a query or other operation on the php page when search is empty? So I need ajax to send me all results from the database when field is empty.

Comment: Can you clarify your question and post the code that you are using?

Comment: Maybe I don't completely understand your question, but have you tried `isset()` or `empty()` ?

Comment: yes I added some code above. thanks.

Comment: yeah but if you look in the xml http open it sends the data to query.php? q="+str so it doesnt send data when the get query is empty so I would need to modify that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm going a bit off-topic here, but I would like to suggest a completely different technique for your particular case.

Here goes: At the time of initial page load, download all search results on the web page. When the user enters some text in the search box, just parse the search results on the web page at client side using JavaScript. When the user deletes the entered text, again use JavaScript to display all the search results. This way, you don't have to send HTTP requests for each "input" by the user, thus increasing the response time between the user entering some text and getting the related search results.

Again, my answer may be off-topic, but I implemented this a while ago and the results were amazing compared to sending GET/POST requests again and again.

Send JSON from PHP to JavaScript on page load:

```
<?php

    function get_all_search_results()
    {
        // Database query to get all search results in an array
        $search_results_array = "";

        // Convert the array to a JSON object
        $json = json_encode($search_results_array);

        // Echo it
        echo $json;
    }

?>
```

At page load, call the above function by an onload JavaScript function like this:
        // JSON object
        var searchResultsArray;

```
    function getAllSearchResults()
    {
        // An ajax request to get all search results in a variable
        var allresults = // result of the ajax request

        // JSON decode the results
        searchResultsArray = JSON.parse(allresults);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah but the results are php objects in an array so I would I send these to javascript?

Comment: Do you want to display all search results when the page first loads and the search box is empty?

Comment: yes well im able to display all the results with the page loads in php before something is typed in the search box. The problem is when someone types something and then erases it and search field becomes empty again I cannot query a empty $_GET on the succes php page it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: You can either store the search results returned from PHP page as a JavaScript variable (for example, send JSON from PHP and decode it to a variable in JavaScript), or just display them on the HTML page and interact with the HTML through JavaScript when user inputs anything in the search box.

Comment: how can i send the json encode variable from php to javascript?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127012/discussion-between-nvj-and-coder-1432).

Comment: Hey just wanted to let you know that your solution is working. Im getting there. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send a `GET` request with no query string. In fact, whenever you hit a webpage using with your browser, you *are* sending a `GET` request, e.g. when you type `http://google.com` in the address bar and hit enter, your browser sends  `GET` request to the URI and google server returns its page.

As Mardzis noted in comments, you can use `empty()` function in your PHP code:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_GET['query'])) {

    $query = $_GET['query'];

    // Return results for specific query...

} else {

    // Return all results...

}
```

**EDIT**

Since you've posted your Javascript code, I noticed something:

```
function showResults(str) {
if (str.length == 0) {
    // If str is empty - isn't this where you want your "empty" query? But you don't
} else {
    // If str is not empty, you send the request.
}
```

Seems like if `str` is empty, you're not sending the request at all. Am I correct?

Comment: Well as I mentionned above I already tried with all the possible combinations with isset and empty and doesnt work

Comment: Yes but I also tried deleting the if str.length==0 and I have the same results the php page doesnt send anything when get query is empty. Maybe I need to put these results into json and then send it to javascript to process it in the if str.length==0 .

Comment: Could you then show us both updated `showResults` js function and full PHP code?

Comment: The showresults js function is the same as the one above minus the str.length==0 which was taken off to try to allow a response because I thought that might block the response.

Comment: is there a way to send sucess on empty get string?

Comment: Yes, `if (empty($_GET)) { echo 'success'; }`. Still, with the code in the question I can't really help.